# Access Cookie in Appsync Lambda authorization instead of authorizationToken

Tags: cookies, aws-appsync, lambda-authorizer

I am trying to access the cookies inside Lambda authoriser of aws appsync but I am not able to do it.

As per [AWS Docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-lambda-auth/) if authorizationToken is not present then graphql itself return to unauthorised to user.

Any Guidance and references will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

One possible way you could achieve this is to;

- Expose your lambda through CloudFront distribution.
- Create the most straightforward CloudFront Function that reads your cookie and sets the header on the viewer request to pass it down to your appsync.
- Have a custom lambda authorizer on your AppSycn that processes the
  cookie value and returns the value for the resolver context.